# Reuse Fragment with flexible listeners

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Fragment which contains a Button. I want to reuse this Fragment, so the OnClickListener isn't hard coded but defined by the activity which calls this Fragment. The Activity implements the needed interface for this and the Fragment gets a reference in its oncreate method.

I have two questions on this below

```
public void TestFragment extends Fragment {

    ...
    private IAction mAction = null;

    @Override 
    public void OnAttach(Context ctx) {
        mAction = (Action) getActivity();
    }

    @Override    
    public void onClickListener() { 
        action(this); 
    }

    public interface IAction { 
        void action(Fragment f); 
    }

    ...
}


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IAction {
    ...

    public void onCreate() {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.content, Testfragment.gestInstance()
                    .commit();
    }

    public void IAction(Fragment f) { 
        f.doSomething()...
    } 

    ...
}
```

1. Is this a good practice to build reusable fragments?
2. I would to extend this: If this fragment is opened by an activity it uses the action defined in the activity. Ok, this works. It's the current behaviour.

But maybe this fragment is opened by another fragment (nested), so getActivity is wrong. Is there something like

```
if(parent.isActivity) {
  mAction = (Action) getActivity()
} else if(parent.isFragment) {
  mAction = (Action) getParentFragment()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getActivity()` will still work even if the fragment is nested within another one.

But if you want to deligate it on the parent fragment, you can use `getParentFragment()`

```
if (getParentFragment() != null) {
   // fragment is nested
} else {
   // not nested
}
```